# Disable Airflow auth

Tags: docker, authentication, airflow

I build image FROM *astronomerinc/ap-airflow:1.10.12-1-alpine3.10-onbuild* and run container.
I don't want the login function.

How to disable auth function.

I saw airflow.cfg [github](https://github.com/astronomer/ap-airflow/blob/master/1.10.10/alpine3.10/Dockerfile)

```
[webserver]
authenticate = False
```

Still need to log in.

[image]

Comment: I did not find a way to do this using Airflow 2.0+. If you use Airflow < 2.0 then the default is that there is no authentication enabled though.